# PySpark PandasUDF on GCP - Memory Allocation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc, pyarrow

I am using a pandas udf to train many ML models on GCP in Dataproc (Spark). The main idea is that I have a grouping variable that represents the various sets of data in my data frame and I run something like this:

```
@pandas_udf(schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def test_train(grp_df):
    
  #train model on grp_df
  #evaluate model 
  #return metrics on 
 
    return (metrics)

result=df.groupBy('group_id').apply(test_train)
```

This works fine except when I use the non-sampled data, where errors are returned that appear to be related to memory issues. The messages are cryptic (to me) but if I sample down the data it runs, if I dont, it fails. Error messages are things like:

> OSError: Read out of bounds (offset = 631044336, size = 69873416) in
> file of size 573373864

or

> Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits.  24.5 GB of 24
> GB physical memory used. Consider boosting
> spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead or disabling
> yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled because of YARN-4714.

My Question is how to set memory in the cluster to get this to work?

I understand that each group of data and the process being ran needs to fit entirely in the memory of the executor. I current have a 4-worker cluster with the following:

[image]

If I think the maximum size of data in the largest group_id requires 150GB of memory, it seems I really need each machine to operate on one group_id at a time. At least I get 4 times the speed compared to having a single worker or VM.

If I do the following, is this in fact creating 1 executor per machine that has access to all the cores minus 1 and 180 GB of memory? So that if in theory the largest group of data would work on a single VM with this much RAM, this process should work?

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
  .appName('test') \
  .config('spark.executor.memory', '180g') \
  .config('spark.executor.cores', '63') \
  .config('spark.executor.instances', '1') \
  .getOrCreate()
```

Comment: Would it be possible to use multiple workers? As you are running the algorithm on different groups, I am wondering that maybe it can be run  on each of them and split on different machines (executors).

Answer (score 2):

Let's break the answer into 3 parts:

1. Number of executors
2. The GroupBy operation
3. Your executor memory

**Number of executors**

Straight from the [Spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html):

```
 spark.executor.instances

 Initial number of executors to run if dynamic allocation is enabled.
 If `--num-executors` (or `spark.executor.instances`) is set and larger
 than this value, it will be used as the initial number of executors.
```

So, **No**. *You only get a single executor which won't scale up unless dynamic allocation is enabled.*

You can increase the number of such executors manually by configuring `spark.executor.instances` or setup automatic scale up based on workload, by enabling dynamic executor allocation.

To enable dynamic allocation, you have to also enable the shuffle service which allows you to safely remove executors. This can be done by setting two configs:

1. `spark.shuffle.service.enabled` to `true`. Default is false.
2. `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled` to `true`. Default is false.

**GroupBy**

I have observed `group_by` being done using hash aggregates in Spark which means given `x` number of partitions, and unique group_by values greater than `x`, multiple group by values will lie in the same partition.

For example, say two unique values in group_by column are `a1` and `a2` having total rows' size 100GiB and 150GiB respectively.

If they fall into separate partitions, your application will run fine since each partition will fit into the executor memory (180GiB), which is required for in-memory processing and the remaining will be spilled to disk if they do not fit into the remaining memory. However, if they fall into same partition, your partition will not fit into the executor memory (180GiB < 250GiB) and you will get an OOM.

In such instances, it's useful to configure `spark.default.parallelism` to distribute your data over a reasonably larger number of partitions or apply salting or other techniques to remove data skewness.

If your data is not too skewed, you are correct to say that as long as your executor can handle the largest groupby value, it should work since your data will be evenly partitioned and chances of the above happening will be rare.

Another point to note is that since you are using `group_by` which requires data shuffle, you should also turn on the shuffle service. Without the shuffle service, each executor has to serve the shuffle requests along with doing it's own work.

**Executor memory**

The total executor memory (actual executor container size) in Spark is determined by adding the executor memory alloted for container along with the alloted `memoryOverhead`. The `memoryOverhead` accounts for things like VM overheads, interned strings, other native overheads, etc. So,

```
Total executor memory = (spark.executor.memory + spark.executor.memoryOverhead)
spark.executor.memoryOverhead = max(executorMemory*0.10, 384 MiB)
```

Based on this, you can configure your executors to have an appropriate size as per your data.
So, when you set the `spark.executor.memory` to `180GiB`, the actual executor launched should be of around `198GiB`.

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure if I follow completely. The algorithm being used is not distributed, it can only run on a single machine where the entire input data fits into memory. So wouldnt I want only a few executors, each that has access to a lot of memory -- what would you change in my config statement to run large memory models?

Comment: Given the setup of the cluster above and a dataset with say 50 distinct values in the groupby, where some of the data in a group is as large as 120GB and the groupby is to fit models for each of the parts of the data frame (the 50), what would you set the config to?

Comment: As far as I understand, your algorithm works on each group by value. Correct me if I am wrong. So, the largest group by value should fit into the memory (120GB) if you have your executor memory (spark.executor.memory > 120GB), the partition should fit in.

Comment: By default, Spark has parallelism set to 200, but there are only 50 distinct values, so fitting them into partitions should not be an issue. Spark will spill the partitions onto disk if there is not enough memory on a single executor, which will make your application a bit slow but would not stop it. I would recommend increasing the number of executors and cores per executor `spark.executor.cores` to as much as possible (this directly relates to how many parallel tasks can run since one runs per core).

Comment: This may be my lack of knowledge (which is great) with how Spark works -- Im a data scientist who uses it for model development and SQL but i dont have the knowledge of the inner workings sadly.

I read the spec on the cluster as saying that each machine has 240GB of RAM total. So, if I need max of 120GB does that not mean that I should allocate a single executor? I have read that each model would be trained in a single executor.

Comment: Are we using `SparkML` for model training?

Comment: No. I dont *think* you can use mllib in such a manner? Think single node vanilla sklearn as in this : http://patrickroos.org/2019/02/25/training-many-scikit-learn-models-using-pyspark-and-pandas-udfs/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222628/discussion-between-amit-singh-and-b-miner).

Answer (score 0):

To Resolve yarn overhead issue you can increase yarn overhead memory by adding `.config('spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead','30g')` and for maximum parallelism it is recommended to keep no of cores to 5 where as you can increase the no of executors.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
  .appName('test') \
  .config('spark.executor.memory', '18g') \
  .config('spark.executor.cores', '5') \
  .config('spark.executor.instances', '12') \
  .getOrCreate()  

# or use dynamic resource allocation refer below config 

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName('test') \
   .config('spark.shuffle.service.enabled':'true')\
   .config('spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled':'true')\
   .getOrCreate()
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved OSError: Read out of bounds ****
by making group number large

result=df.groupBy('group_id').apply(test_train)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).